# Angular HttpInterceptor errorResponse has the wrong status

Tags: angularjs, rest, error-handling, http-status-codes, angular-http-interceptors

The server returns a 403 Forbidden status, but angular interceptor retrieves a -1 status... any ideas?

Options request returns a 200 OK...

[image]
[image]

Comment: What was your solution?  I'm currently confused by this.  If my API returns 200 then interceptors not called if API returns 403 then interceptors just get a status of '-1'.  Not sure how to solve this.

Answer (score 0):

**In Angular :**

response status -1 means that the API is offline (CONNECTION_REFUSED) since Angular 1.3.19 (before the status code was 0) which means that the url you try to call does not exist (hence there is no server listening to this call)

**In HTTP protocol :**

403 means FORBIDDEN. The server understood the request but refuses to authorize it. A server that wishes to make public why the request has been forbidden can describe that reason in the response payload (if any).

If authentication credentials were provided in the request, the server considers them insufficient to grant access.

Comment: Yes indeed, that is my question... How come angular tells me that the connection was refused, while the server responded with code 403 forbidden?
I fixed the problem already, since it was a CORS problem that allowed the options request to pass, but failed on the request itself. But this does not explain the strange behavior of a mismatch between angular and the effective request